# При сборке бинарника не выкачивается модуль из приватного репозитория

Tags: golang, github, модули, privacy

Использую модули, пытаюсь собрать бинарник, в импортах указан приватный репозиторий. Возникает ошибка:

> ```
> filepath/file.go:9:2: cannot find module providing package
> github.com/RepoName/modulename: module github.com/RepoName/modulename:
> git ls-remote -q origin in /pacagePath: exit status 128:
>     fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled Confirm the import path was entered
>     correctly. If this is a private repository, see
>     https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
> ```

Я делаю все, чтобы исправить ошибку как описано в https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https но это не помогает.

UPD: в .netrc добавлены учетные данные, ошибка изменилась на:

> remote: Repository not found.
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/reponame/' not found

Comment: Что значит «делаю всё»?  Ваш `.netrc` содержит ваш *Github*-логин и сгенерированный свежий ключ для *API* (**не** пароль)?

Comment: Создал .netrc с верными данными, теперь ошибка поменялась:

remote: Repository not found.
        fatal: repository 'https://github.com/reponame/' not found

Comment: по ссылке из ошибки репозиторий доступен

Comment: `GOPRIVATE="github.com/reponame"` делали?

Comment: да, та же ошибка